# Extract text before the first comma in each line of a text file

Tags: python, regex, file

I have a file that looks like this:

```
Breve, a writ; used more frequently in the plural brevia. 
Brevia magistralia, official writs framed by the clerks in 
chancery to meet new injuries, to which the old forms of action 
were inapplicable. Sea Trespass on the case. Brevia testata, 
short attested memoranda, originally introduced to obviate the 
uncertainty arisina; from parol feoffments, hence modern con- 
veyances have gradually arisen.
```

i want to extract the words that appear before the first comma(,) in each line

Expected Output:

```
Breve
Brevia magistralia
chancery to meet new injuries
were inapplicable. Sea Trespass on the case. Brevia testata
short attested memoranda
uncertainty arisina; from parol feoffments
```

my code:

```
with open('test.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line[0:line.find(',')])
```

output:

```
Breve
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: `.+?(?=,[^.]+\.)` 

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/YhNuVd/2

Comment: I get a longer output.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need regex? `str.split` should be good enough.

```
with open('test.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        text = line.split(',', 1)[0] # add nsplits = 1 for efficiency 
        ... # do something with text
```

---

However, if you really need regex, you could use something like:

```
for line in file:
        m = re.match('[^,]+', line)
        if m:
            text = m.group(0)
```

Where `[^,]+` matches anything from the start that isn't a comma ([credits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46190206/python-extract-word-before-1st-string-occurrence-in-each-line-in-text-file/46190293?noredirect=1#comment79342716_46190293)).

Comment: No need for a lazy dot and lookahead, just `re.match('[^,]+', line)` will do.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for helping me improve my regex. :-)

Comment: @coldspeed i tried both your approaches and they arent going past the first line.
My output is 'Breve'

Comment: @Ashksta Something wrong with your file... or your code.

Answer (score 1):

Short `re.findall()` solution:

```
import re
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    result = re.findall(r'^[^,]+(?=,)', f.read(), re.M)   # extracting the needed words
    print('\n'.join(result))
```

The output:

```
Breve
Brevia magistralia
chancery to meet new injuries
were inapplicable. Sea Trespass on the case. Brevia testata
short attested memoranda
uncertainty arisina; from parol feoffments
```

Answer (score 1):

You are going well just do this modifications,

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as fd:
    for line in fd:
        index = line.find(',')
        if index >= 0:
            print line[0:index]
```

OUTPUT:

```
Breve
Brevia magistralia
chancery to meet new injuries
were inapplicable. Sea Trespass on the case. Brevia testata
short attested memoranda
uncertainty arisina; from parol feoffments
```

Comment: Modified your logic @Ashksta

Answer (score 1):

This one of the additional answer, where you can use re.search:

```
import re
with open('test.txt','r') as file:
    for line in file:
       # print(line)
        result = re.search(r'^[^,]+(?=,)', line )
        if result:
            text = result.group(0)
            print(text)
```

**Output:**

```
Breve
Brevia magistralia
chancery to meet new injuries
were inapplicable. Sea Trespass on the case. Brevia testata
short attested memoranda
uncertainty arisina; from parol feoffments
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code but I got correct output according to your question

Output:

```
Breve
Brevia magistralia
chancery to meet new injuries
were inapplicable. Sea Trespass on the case. Brevia testata
short attested memoranda
uncertainty arisina; from parol feoffments
veyances have gradually arisen.
```

**Therefore make sure your input file itself is correct**

**Probably your test file doesn't have new lines** , i.e the whole text is written as one line only.so only the first word is printed and then a comma is found so no more words are printed.

Note: the last sentence , no comma is found so all the words are printed (*which is different than your expected output*)

Comment: @COLDSPEED I tried the code , it is working , the file seems written as one line only

Comment: kindly check the output @AhmedElkoussy,  You got wrong

Comment: @Sanket Thanks for feedback , can you please elaborate what is wrong in the output ? I took the output (copy paste) from my PyCharm terminal

Comment: check the last line,  no `comma` is there,  still you were displaying it, Also that is not in question also